# How to append to file using seekg and seekp in c++, without using ios::app flag

Tags: c++, iostream, seekg

I am not getting proper output while using seekp and seekg function, while on the other hand when I use ios::app for appending, program works well. How should I use seekg(), and seekp() functions for appending on a file?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream.h>
void main()
{            clrscr();

ofstream out;
out.open("MJ");
char data[100];
cout<<"\nEnter data: ";
cin.getline(data,100);
out<<data;
out.close();
ifstream in;
in.open("MJ");

in>>data;
cout<<data;

in.close();


out.open("MJ");

cout<<"\nEnter data: ";
cin.getline(data,100);
out.seekp(2);
out<<data;

out.close();

in.open("MJ");
in>>data;
cout<<data<<endl;


     getch();

}
```

Comment: Instead of `std::ios::app` you can use `std::ios::ate` to open the file with the file pointer already at the end of the file (but not in append mode). Maybe show us what you did and we can see where you are going wrong?

Comment: You do know that [`seekp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp) and [`seekg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) affects different file pointers?

Comment: And can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Edited the quetion: 
This is how I want the program to work, It takes the first text say "ava"
then it takes Text as "cardo" output should be "avacardo"

Comment: @Galik I want to use only file pointer seekg and seekp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `out.seekp(2)` you only seek two *bytes* into the file, and then overwrite whatever is beyond that, but that's not the problem.

The problem is is when you reopen the file the old contents is destroyed, the file is truncated. You need to open the file in `open | in` mode to not destroy content, if you want to manually seek to the end:

```
out.open("MJ", ios::out | ios::in);
```

<sub>It's okay to open an "output" stream in `ios::in` mode.</sub>

See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) which have a nice table of modes and what they do and mean.

Comment: Thank a Lot sir!
but i thought 0- means at beg 1 - means at current and - at end.